# Java template with primitivedata types as C++ templates

Tags: java, templates

I want to implement a function in Java using templates/generics the same way I can do in C++. I've tried to use generics in Java with primitive values (int, double,...), but for the function mean below I got the following error from the compiler:

> error: bad operand types for binary operator '+' sum += value; first
>   type: double second type: T where T is a type-variable: T extends
>   Object declared in method mean(T[])

I've tried to replace T for a different value but couldn't find an answer. What is the correct way to do it?

```
// Java code
private <T> double mean(T[] data) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (T value : data)
        sum += value;

    return sum / data.length;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply spoken: you can't.

In contrast to C++ templates; Java generics **only** work with *reference* aka "Object" types. And no, there is no way around that.

The key thing here: Java generics are **not** the same thing as C++ templates.

On the C++ side, the compiler really creates type-specific code out of your template. For java, generics are (not much more than) *syntactic sugar* around methods that take *Object* parameters. In other words: the compiler does all the casting so that it looks like your `List<String>` really only works with strings. But there is no special/different compilation unit for `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`. There is just a List.class that works with Object all over the place.

So the essential answer is: the fact that two concepts look syntactically identical in two different programming language ... does not make them **semantically** the same.

And for the record: as the other answer suggests, you can use something like `<T extends Number>` and another dose of syntactic sugar (called auto-boxing resp. unboxing) kicks in. But beware of the consequences: auto-boxing basically translates to: creation of *intermediate* Long, Integer, ... objects. In other words: used extensively, there can be a **major** performance impact (for example when working on really large arrays with primitive values); as there is nothing "worse" than creating a lot of Objects that immediately turn into "garbage" (and thus trigger GC activity!)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have generic functions with primitive type parameters in Java.

You can approximate a solution using boxed primitives (`java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Double` etc), and the fact that all these classes implement the `java.lang.Number` interface.

A solution using arrays:

```
private static <T extends Number> double mean(T[] data) { 
    double sum = 0;
    for (T number : data)
        sum += number.doubleValue();

    return sum / data.length;
} 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Double[] data = new Double[] {12.0, 16.0};
    System.out.println(mean(data));
}
```